# How to set redux initial state for array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, redux

I am using redux for my react app. I am fetching user data from api, updating redux state with it and showing it into my component. The data is list of objects. The thing what causes me problem is setting redux initial state.

Reducer initial state:

```
const initState = {
    users: []
}
```

Reducer action

```
case 'GET_USERS':
    return {
        users: action.users
    }
});
```

Render in component

```
{this.props.users[1].name}
```

On first rendering i am getting error can't read from undefined property. That is cause on first rendering data isn't stored yet and that object with that property doesn't exist yet. I can solve that if i set initial state like:

```
const initState = {
    users: [
        {name: "", age: ""},
        {name: "", age: ""}
    ]
}
```

In that case object with property would exist and i wouldn't get error. But i don't know how many objects i will have and i don't want to set initial state for every of them and theirs properties. So what is the way to properly set it?

Comment: You need iterate the array with a map, for example, and render the item inside the map. In this case, if the array is empty, no rendering would take place.

Comment: I think you should expand your render method to fully show us what you're attempting to output.

Answer (score 1):

Just check if it is present and render conditionally

```
{this.props.users.length > 1 ? this.props.users[1].name : 'Not enough elements!'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't render a user by its position like that. Either you iterate all users or look into normalizing your data

```
<div>
  {users.map(user) => (
    <div>{users.name}</div>
  )}
</div>
```

https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape

Comment: but it doesn't work when it goes deeper.. for example users.name.firstname

Answer (score 0):

I would use an empty array and check for the [].length property before rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You mention your object structure

```
{name: "", age: ""}
```

and then you mention how to access `users.name.firstname`. If you get an `undefined` that means your dara hasn't loaded into your users array. So, instantiate with an empty array such as `users:[]` and add the following:

```
const YourComponent = (props) => {
  if (users.length === 0){
    return <div> Loading </div>
  }
  return(
    <div>
      {users.map(user => 
        <div>
          {user.name}
        </div>  
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Your component will load before your array will be populated and will return the Loading div. When the array will be filled, the component will rerender and will map out your array.

Comment: i know for that approach but i want to avoid using if statement in every component, surely there has to be  a better way of doing it

Comment: This is common practice so unless you have a specific reason behind it, you can use it in all of your components. Alternatively, check out react-loadable